# Подсчитать комбинации 01 и 10

Tags: java

Нужно узнать количество комбинаций 01 и 10 для заданного двоичного числа, я подумал что это можно сделать через массив, вводя по одному разряду в каждый элемент массива.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test1 {

static int count = 0;
static ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String[] s = { "1", "0", "0", "1", "1" };
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length + 1; i++)
        permutate(s, i);
    for (String string : arrList)
        System.out.println(++count + ": " + string);
}

public static void permutate(String[] arr, int limit) {
    permuteIteration(arr, 0, limit);
}

private static void permuteIteration(String[] arr, int index, int limit) {

    if (index >= limit) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            sb.append(arr[i] + " ");
        arrList.add(sb.toString());
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        return;
    }

    for (int i = index; i < arr.length; i++) {
        String temp = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;

        permuteIteration(arr, index + 1, limit);

        temp = arr[index];
        arr[index] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

В выводе я получаю все возможные комбинации из этих чисел (00,01,11,10).
Пример вывода предоставлю

```
1: 1 0 
2: 0 1 
3: 0 0 
4: 1 0 
5: 1 0 
6: 1 0 
7: 1 0 
......
320: 1 1 
321: 1 1 
322: 1 1 
323: 1 1 
324: 1 1 
325: 1 1
```

И теперь возникает вопрос как оставить только нужные мне комбинации?

Comment: не очень понятно, что делает этот код и что он вообще должен делать. Зачем делать какие-то перестановки и потом удалять ненужные, когда сразу известно, что нужны только 01 и 10?

Comment: Видел что похожим способом находили комбинации букв, решил что он может считать и мои символы, а после взять с него нужные

Comment: С чего "с него"? Вы не понимаете разницу между количеством и комбинациями? Вам в предыдущем вопросе уже написали, как нужно считать, не нужно ничего придумывать.

Answer (score -1):

А я так подумал, что нужно подсчитать количество последовательностей 01 и 10 в двоичной записи числа. Если так, то вот (правда, на другом языке, но алгоритм должен быть понятен):

```
using System;
namespace test1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            int i = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < number.Length - 1; j++) if (number.Substring(j, 2) == "01") i++;
            Console.WriteLine("01: {0}", i);
            i = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < number.Length - 1; j++) if (number.Substring(j, 2) == "10") i++;
            Console.WriteLine("10: {0}", i);
        }
    }
}
```